# What is the output of transformation by a $3 × 2$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know a $3 × 2$ matrix transforms $2$-dimensional vectors to $3$-dimensional vectors. So the input could be a plane, but what about output? Is it always a plane in a $3$-dimensional space? I know the column space of the matrix is $2$.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a plane in a 3D space, but not just any plane: it is a plane that contains the origin $(0,0,0)$, since a linear transformation maps a zero vector to a zero vector.

Comment: Thanks, are the basis vectors of this plane, the two columns of the matrix?

Comment: The columns of the matrix span the plane, yes (but note that they can be non-orthogonal).